# Insert multiple values in One Single column SQLITE

Tags: python, sqlite

How to insert multiple values from list items into one single column of database and the below command didnot work for me

```
tags = item['tag']


for EveryTag in item['tag']:
    #print (EveryTag)
     Values = (str(EveryTag))
     Query = """insert into yellow_pages_tb (tag) values (?)  , ('""" + Values +  """') """
     self.curr.execute(Query)
self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: Do you mean ...insert a list (like a String) in a column?

Comment: Your question is far from clear. This being said: 1/ [learn to use the db api correctly](https://bobby-tables.com/) and 2/ [a sql database field's value is supposed to be atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: It is very obvious,  i need to know how to insert a list items in one single column of table regardless those items are string or integer,  plz help as much as you can

Comment: `execute(Query, (value,))`

Comment: you have to send value as second argument in `execute()` - not as string in `Query` - and it will put it in place of `(?)`. BTW: If want to insert many rows then you even use `executemany(Query, item['tag'])` without `for`-loop